# URL.createObjectURL() not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my web extension I need to convert a file from a Blob to an array so I can store it in web extension storage.
However when I want to convert it back and use it as an image it doesn't really work.

```
// converting to a normal array to store in storage
const myArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(await myBlob.arrayBuffer()));
chrome.storage.local.set({image: myArray});
```

now from my background script:

```
const myArray = (await chrome.storage.local.get()).image;

console.log(URL.createObjectUrl(new Blob(Uint8Array.from(myArray), { type: "image/png" })));
```

The console.log produces a link which brings me to a white image, which is not what the image is. And I do know for sure that myArray transfers correctly through the storage since even if I try to do URL.createObjectURL() without storage it produces the same result.

And if I don't convert it into an array and back it does work so I am unsure what is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `myArray` have the value that you expect?

Comment: Yes, myArray has the value I expect since it's just a ton of numbers between 0 and 255 in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it should be:

```
new Blob([Uint8Array.from(myArray)], { type: "image/png" })
```

instead of

```
new Blob(Uint8Array.from(myArray), { type: "image/png" })
```